# Can not start Certbot container Laradock

Tags: certbot, laradock

#### Info:

- Docker version: 17.06.2-ce
- System info version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

#### Issue:

My website is already in use. I used laradock with nginx. Now, I want to use Certbot to get SSL certificate for my website. I tried with `docker-compose up certbot` and this error shown up

> Starting beetracklaradock_certbot_1 ...
>
> Starting beetracklaradock_certbot_1 ... done
>
> Attaching to beetracklaradock_certbot_1
>
> certbot_1              | Failed authorization procedure. example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/GPhVi_ohWUFffHLuTC_co6PkJf4qz1Jg16dyvmZIJL0: "
>
> certbot_1              | 404 Not Found
>
> certbot_1              |
>
> certbot_1              |
>
> ## 404 Not Found
>
> certbot_1              |
>
> ---
>
> "

My access log:

```
GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/GPhVi_ohWUFffHLuTC_co6PkJf4qz1Jg16dyvmZIJL0 HTTP/1.1" 404 136 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Let's Encrypt validation server; +https://www.letsencrypt.org)
```

Here is my laravel.conf

```
# mariadb20

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name example.com;
root /var/www/example/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

... // same as example laravel.conf

location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    default_type "text/plain";
    root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
    log_not_found off;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/example_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log;
```

I tried some other discussion. I did `docker-compose exec workspace bash` and created a file in var/www/letsencrypt and I can not access to that file using www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/myfile.

Furthermore, I can see that Certbot container did not create any file on letsencrypt folder.

Is there any wrong? Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Had similar issues. Seems it was not set up properly with two containers (nginx and certbot) that both depend on each other and with a web root that is accessible. Have a look at https://github.com/Larastudio/lsdock/blob/master/prod-docker-compose.yml .  Based on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose I added a new Certbot image with proper interdependence and volumes. Though Nginx is not quite done config wise at the time of this writing it should help you.